# Proving that for all real numbers, R, the area of a rectangle is equal to R and its perimter is greate than 4R

Tags: logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

**What I've done.**

I figured that to make the rectangles perimeter greater than $4r$, I would have to choose a length that is possible of that.
Let the area of a rectangle equal $r$.

$$(l*w)= r$$

then we know the perimeter has to be greater than $4r$ so

we let $p  4r$,
and substitute for $p$ and $r$ to get

$2(w+l) > 4(w*l)$ solve for $l$ to get

$$w+l > 2(w*l)$$

$$w > 2wl-l$$

$$w > l(2w-1)$$

$$ \frac wl > 2w-1$$

$$ \frac1l >  \frac{(2w-1)}{w} $$

$$l < -  \frac{w}{(2w-1)} $$

therefore for any real number $r$ the area of a rectangle will be eqaual to $r$ and its perimeter will be greater than $4r$ when $l < -  \frac{w}{(2w-1)} $

Just trying to see if this proof makes sense.

Comment: This is hard to read. You appear to assume that $p>4R$ from the start, which you can't do if you are trying to prove it.  For a square of side $1$ we have $p=4$ and a square is a rectangle, so your claim is false as stated.  In general, the [Arithmetic Geometric Mean Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) does show that $L+W≥4LW$ when $L,W≥0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ and $h$ be the width of the rectangle.  You are requested to find suitable values for $w$ and $h$ so that
\begin{gather}
w\cdot h = R \\
2 w + 2 h > 4 \cdot R
\end{gather}

Inserting the first equation into the second inequation, you obtain :
$$
2 w + 2 \frac{R}{w} > 4 R
$$
Assuming the non degenerate case that $w>0$.
\begin{gather}
w + \frac{R}{w} > 2 R\\
w^2-2Rw + R > 0
\end{gather}

Solving, you obtain :
$$
w = \frac{2R \pm \sqrt{ 4R^2 - 4R}}{2} = R \pm \sqrt{R^2-R}
$$

The term of degree 2 having a positive sign, the second degree polynomial is positive at the extreme ("outside" of the roots), thus you should pick $w< R-\sqrt{R^2-R}$ or $w> R-\sqrt{R^2-R}$.